# Choosing CRS to use for South Africa that will give map scale in meters in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, map-unit, south-africa

This has been a constant source of frustration for me. I can't seem to always get my map scale in meters in QGIS, even if I use a CRS that has map units of meters, e.g. Alberts Equal Area and others. Sometimes it works, but most of the time it doesn't.

I usually work with an area of a few square kilometers. I then have to georeference a satellite image of the area and load my different vector and raster data. 
Let's specifically look at the georeferencing, I first deselect OTF, then I select my GCP points and set my transformation type. Then I select the CRS, e.g. Hartebeeshoek94/Lo25 (map units = meters) and run the georeferencer. The result is a georeferenced satellite image with the correct coordinates but a scale of 1:1. The scale bar is then also completely incorrect in the map composer.
I have now found that every time I save the georeferenced image as a CRS with the units in meters, the scale loads as a 1:1. When I load the layer as a CRS with map units in degrees, the scale is correct by the scale bar is still incorrect in the map composer (as would be expected).

Comment: Would you be able to [edit] your question to detail the precise steps that you performed to get the first problem that you mention, please?  As per the [tour] there should be one question/problem per question posed here.

Comment: Also can you indicate what you are trying to do, that you need to view the entire country in a projected CS? One would normally set it to the local projection for the area e.g. LO19 for Cape Town, LO31 for Durban etc.

Comment: Are you georeferencing by clicking on the map canvas, or by entering coordinates manually?

Comment: I use the map canvas

Comment: You have to choose the same CRS as the map canvas is.